# Dialog Box Placement in VS 6

Tags: c++, dialog, visual-studio-6

I'm modifying a C++ program using visual studio 6.  I changed the order in which two dialog boxes were initialized and now the dialog box that is displayed second (the one previously initialized first,  now initialized second) does not appear in the same position on the screen and instead now overlaps the other dialog box.

The overlapping occurs at the x 0, y 0 coordinates of the dialog box it overlaps.  I speculated that after switching the order they were initialized it changed the point of reference of the second dialog box to that of the first which would explain why they overlap but before I made my change the now overlapping dialog box did not appear at the most upper left corner of the screen (although it was in that general area).

What exactly controls the placement of dialog boxes on the screen and what is the best way to move them in relation to others?

I noticed I could change the x and y position in the properties of dialog boxes to accomplish this or use the MoveWindow function but was wondering if there was a better way.  If not, is there a better way to determine the number of pixels without guessing and checking?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't think you've provided nearly enough information for anyone to help you. Also, did you know that VS 6 was released in 1998 or so?

Comment: It is set by the "X Pos" and "Y Pos" values in the dialog editor.  Yes, they default to 0, relative from its owner.  Change it.

Comment: Yes, I realize VS 6 is quite dated.  Thanks for answering my question Hans Passant.